# raspberry pi and nayax device payment gateway communication using usb port of raspberry pi3

Tags: serial-port, payment-gateway, raspberry-pi3, mdb2

for my project of vending machine using raspberry pi .I need to connect raspberry pi with nayax payment device which is based on marshall protocol .The connection between raspberry pi and nayax device is using ttyUSB0 port.
nayax device programming is seen using mdb to rs232 with its amit device and pc using visual studio. can anyone tell how i can run nayax with raspbery pi

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?